# Pulling specific objects from xml file in python

Tags: python, xml, parsing

Trying to strip out only the domain names listed in this xml page:
https://us-cert.cisa.gov/sites/default/files/publications/AA20-301A.stix.xml

So from the data below:

```
<indicator:Title>Malicious FQDN Indicator</indicator:Title>
<indicator:Type xsi:type="stixVocabs:IndicatorTypeVocab-1.1">Domain Watchlist</indicator:Type>
<indicator:Observable id="CISA:Observable-1a97193f-7206-4bda-aadb-a9876943629b">
<cybox:Object id="CISA:Object-8ee878fd-147c-4438-be3a-ad61470eec80">
<cybox:Properties xsi:type="DomainNameObj:DomainNameObjectType" type="FQDN">
<DomainNameObj:Value condition="Equals">jp-ssl[.]work</DomainNameObj:Value>
</cybox:Properties>
</cybox:Object>
</indicator:Observable>
<indicator:Sightings sightings_count="1">
<indicator:Sighting timestamp="2018-05-01T00:00:00"/>
</indicator:Sightings>
</stix:Indicator>
<stix:Indicator id="CISA:Indicator-90e0da37-5c97-49f1-8fe5-5a4db57513fa" timestamp="2020-10-23T18:29:40.163791+00:00" xsi:type="indicator:IndicatorType">
<indicator:Title>Malicious FQDN Indicator</indicator:Title>
<indicator:Type xsi:type="stixVocabs:IndicatorTypeVocab-1.1">Domain Watchlist</indicator:Type>
<indicator:Observable id="CISA:Observable-40f4bf4d-db81-4560-bbaa-73ce4a9ead99">
<cybox:Object id="CISA:Object-da253d57-6148-435a-ae55-a4a9cd1d4661">
<cybox:Properties xsi:type="DomainNameObj:DomainNameObjectType" type="FQDN">
<DomainNameObj:Value condition="Equals">intemet[.]work</DomainNameObj:Value>
</cybox:Properties>
</cybox:Object>
</indicator:Observable>
<indicator:Sightings sightings_count="1">
<indicator:Sighting timestamp="2018-05-01T00:00:00"/>
</indicator:Sightings>
</stix:Indicator>
```

I want to find a way to print the domains: jp-ssl[.]work, intemet[.]work

(Obfuscated links since they are malicious) Using python to request the contents

Comment: what did you try so far?

Answer (score 0):

Try with Beautifulsoup. Here xml_data is your input data

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(xml_data, 'html.parser')
>>> for tag in soup.find_all('domainnameobj:value'):
...      print(tag.text)

jp-ssl[.]work
intemet[.]work
```